# Create a repeat function in SML

Tags: recursion, sml, smlnj

I am working on creating a function called `repeat` that takes two int lists `lst1` and `lst2`. Assume that `lst2` only has nonnegative integers, repeats the integers in the first list `lst1` according to the numbers indicated by the second list `lst2`. If both lists are empty, return an empty list. You may need a local function.

Example:
`repeat ([1,2,3], [4,0,3])` -> `[1,1,1,1,3,3,3]`

I am having a little trouble with getting started with this function. What should I put after the xs?

```
fun repeat(lst1, lst2) =
    case lst1 of
      [] => []
    | x::xs' => [] (* what should I put here *)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like any recursion problem, what's your base case? I'd say in this case it's both lists are empty and it gives you an empty list.

```ml
fun repeat([], []) = []
```

What if one is empty but the other isn't? That's a failure. Let's define an exception we can throw if this happens.

```ml
exception MismatchedArguments;

fun repeat([], []) = []
  | repeat([], _) = raise MismatchedArguments
  | repeat(_, []) = raise MismatchedArguments
```

Now the real question is what we do the rest of the time. Fortunately, SML makes it easy to pattern match both lists and extract their first elements.

```ml
exception MismatchedArguments;

fun repeat([], []) = []
  | repeat([], _) = raise MismatchedArguments
  | repeat(_, []) = raise MismatchedArguments
  | repeat(x::xs, y::ys) = ...
```

At this point, we need a recursive function to repeat an element of the list a certain number of times. As with the overall function, here we see the two hallmarks of recursion: at least *one* base "exit" condition, and an update step where we converge toward the base condition by updating `n` to `n - 1`.

```ml
exception MismatchedArguments;

fun repeat([], []) = []
  | repeat([], _) = raise MismatchedArguments
  | repeat(_, []) = raise MismatchedArguments
  | repeat(x::xs, y::ys) = 
      let
        fun repeat'(_, 0) = []
          | repeat'(x, n) = x :: repeat'(x, n - 1)
      in
        ...
      end
```

Now, we just need to put it all together, by feeding `x` and `y` to `repeat'` and then concatenating that with the result of calling `repeat` again with `xs` and `ys`. By doing this, we converge down toward the base case of `repeat([], [])` *or* we may converge toward a mismatched scenario where a `MismatchedArguments` exception is raised.

```ml
exception MismatchedArguments;

fun repeat([], []) = []
  | repeat([], _) = raise MismatchedArguments
  | repeat(_, []) = raise MismatchedArguments
  | repeat(x::xs, y::ys) = 
      let
        fun repeat'(_, 0) = []
          | repeat'(x, n) = x :: repeat'(x, n - 1)
      in
        repeat'(x, y) @ repeat(xs, ys)
      end
```

Now `repeat([1, 2, 3], [4, 0, 3])` will yield `[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]`.